# How do I run Ubuntu from the desktop ISO image?

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded a file called ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64 iso image file to my downloads folder. When I try to run the file, Windows starts to configure Sonic RecordNow! (why?) but then reports:

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
> Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'RNENU.msi' in the box below.

where "the box below" contains the string c:\hp\tmp\src\

I've used Windows Explorer to look for RNENU.msi but it couldn't find it in My Computer.

I would like to know how I could use this iso file to install Ubuntu and migrate from windows

Comment: Installing an operating system (be that Linux or Windows) is much more complex than downloading a file and "running" it, I fear. You should really read (**all of**) the instruction on how to install it **before starting**. Start from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the ISO file and, if available, look at the options under "Open with". You should see an alternative program such as "Windows Disc Image Burner" (depending on which version of Windows you are using).

Alternatively, download "ImgBurn" which is a free ISO writing application which will allow you to burn this image to disc avoiding the problematic installation of "Sonic RecordNow!".

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to install Ubuntu is from a USB drive, CD, or DVD. If you have a newer computer which is capable of booting off of a USB drive, you can follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create a bootable Ubuntu USB drive using [Pen Drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

If you do not have access to a USB drive, or your computer cannot boot off of one, you can create a bootable CD or DVD, which will work on almost all computers. Follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) to create a bootable CD or DVD on Windows.